# Need to display angularjs data in my table

Tags: angularjs

I am getting data in controller as below
 $scope.healthData = []; //declare an empty array

```
           $scope.init = function(){
               console.log("before function");
               $http({
                      method: 'GET',
                      url: ''
                    }).then(function successCallback(response) {

                        $scope.healthData = angular.toJson(response.data);

                    }, function errorCallback(response) {
                        alert("Trouble grabbing requested data.")
                    });

                  }
```

and I am trying to display my data in my jsp page as below :

    {{ x.name }}

```
<td>{{ x.componentStatus }}</td>
```

But I am getting below error in the console :
Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/ngRepeat/dupes?p0=x%20in%20healthData&p1=string%3A%22&p2=%22
    at angular.min.js:6

```
at XMLHttpRequest.t.onload (angular.min.js:103)
```

can anyone help me?

Comment: Follow [the white rabbit](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngRepeat/dupes?p0=x%20in%20healthData&p1=string:%22&p2=%22)

Comment: You have duplicates in the model you're trying to bind and you're not managing them correctly. There's a lot of info out there on this topic. Just search for the error.

Comment: tried this.no luck. the error is gone, but data is not displaying

Comment: Can you post your code that shows the entire table including the ng-repeat?

Answer (score 1):

in your ng-repeat just add one line

```
ng-repeat="data in dataset track by $index"
```

This error comes when you have duplicate values in your dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly their is no need to parse the data to json. By default angular only consumes data as Json.

So, just remove

```
$scope.healthData = response.data;
```

Json parsing of data.

By seeing the error.. what i feel is .. the array is containing duplicate values. In case use `trackby` to use some other field as key in `ng-repeat`.

Paste the complete code from `ng-repeat` and `Array` to get the exact problem .

Comment: Yeah Thanks, I am able to print my data now. Again, I am using c3 charts to display the same data.But my json data is not available outside

Comment: use `$scope.healthData` and write the chart code in the controller iteself. Variable will not be accessible outside controller.

Comment: yes my controller scope is there until the end of the js file. when i just exit the http method , when i alert , i am not getting $scope.healthData

Answer (score 0):

You have duplicates of objects ( with same content ) in your data add to ng-repeat `track by $index` or add `track by record.id`